# How to add alert with datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this [reference](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/), specifically the `dp.change` event.. and i want to add an ajax call to send to one of my actions in my controller. But first I want to see the data that is being passed in.

Here is what I have:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change", function (e) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Create")';
            $.get(url, {
                day: $('#Day').val(),
            }, function (data) {
               console.log(data)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where in that script can I add an alert to check if the value I am expecting is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change", function (e) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Create")';
alert($('#Day').val());
alert(url);
        $.get(url, {
            day: $('#Day').val(),
        }, function (data) {
           console.log(data)
        });
    });
});
```